# bootstrap in Java Script file

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to add Bootstrap inside my .js file and make some design changes? 
I'm trying to create on button just to start but is not getting it.

It has a function on the top and html tag on the bottom. Idea is to make a design button for "Total Values".

some help where I should do it and call?

```
var getFieldValues = function() {

    var values = [];
    var sumOfValues = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < workflow_value.length; i++) {
        var fieldName = workflow_value[i];
        var fieldValue = Geopal.getJobWorkflowValueByName(fieldName);
        if (fieldValue && fieldValue != '') {
            questionsAndValues[fieldName] = fieldValue;
        }
    }

    console.log(questionsAndValues);

    //   for (var j = 0; j < workflow_value.length; j++) {
    //     const current_value = Geopal.getJobWorkflowValueByName(workflow_value[j]);
    //     values.push(current_value);
    //   }

    for (var value in questionsAndValues) {
        var current_value = parseFloat(questionsAndValues[value]);
        console.log(current_value);
        if (!isNaN(current_value)) {
            sumOfValues += current_value;
            console.log(sumOfValues);
        } 
        else {
            console.log('invalid values');
        }
    }

    questionsAndValues['Total Value'] = sumOfValues;
};

var okShowText = function(){

};

var cancelShowText = function(){

};



$(document).ready( function() {

   //Geopal.Dialog.showProgressDialog('Loading Data...');

   getFieldValues();

    for (var question in questionsAndValues){
        var rowToAppend =   '<div style="min-height:40px;border-bottom: solid 1px gray"><div style="min-width:38%; max-width:38%; display:inline-block; height:40px; border-right: solid 1px gray"><div style="padding:5%">' +  question + '</div></div>' + 
                            '<div style="min-width:60%; max-width:60%; display:inline-block; margin-left:5px"><div>' +  questionsAndValues[question] + '</div></div></div>'

        $('#detailsView').append(rowToAppend);

         function myFunction() {
        btn = 'Total Value';
        var btn = document.createElement("TOTAL");
        btn.appendChild(t);
        document.body.appendChild(btn);
}
```

Comment: I can't find anything Bootstrap related in your code above

Comment: Thats is my problem! how do I do it? or should just design on here:

Comment: function myFunction() {
        btn = 'Total Value';
        var btn = document.createElement("TOTAL");
        btn.appendChild(t);
        document.body.appendChild(btn);
}

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no idea what you are trying to do. Did you follow the get started quide? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/

Comment: You need to insert the Bootstrap CSS file into your html file. When you create a button via JS you must add the Bootstrap classes (class="btn btn-default") to your element.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Refer [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) CSS file to the HTML file. Add bootstrap classes on creating an element from  javascript function.

If you want to add styles to the button, refer  [Bootstrap Button Styles](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/)

```js
$(function(){

var btn = document.createElement("button");
        btn.setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-primary');
        btn.innerHTML = 'Total Value';
        document.body.appendChild(btn);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<html>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```